# Woprdress мультисайт и .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

WP, мультисайт на 2 сайта (site.ru и name.site.ru)
В .htaccess есть вот такой код (скопировал его из админки, в разделе   установка сети)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

из-за строки

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
```

возникает ошибка
при обращении к файлу, которого физически не существует

```
/wp-content/upload/test/test.jpg
```

отдается ошибка 500
и в логе пишется ошибка

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

Если закомментировать данную строку, то работает как и должно быть. Вместо 500 отдается ошибка 404
Хочется понять за что отвечает данная строка и почему возникает ошибка.
Насколько я понимаю сначала идут условия

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

которые задают условия - *если запрашивается файл или директория, то*
а потом уже RewriteRule
я так понимаю строка говорит, что нужно смотреть в папках

```
wp-admin
wp-content
wp-includes
```

вроде логично, но почему тогда ошибка?
ps
в остальном все работает, ошибок нет.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше даже не закомментить, а видоизменить правило.

Измените

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
```

на

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) - [L]
```

Ошибка 500 с который вы сталкиваетесь, возникает по причине того, что из-за несуществующего файла вы попадаете в цикл ($1), который постоянно пытается перезаписать URL с косой чертой в обратную сторону. Заменяя `$1` на `-` мы избавляемся от цикла перезаписи. По сути проблема кроется в версиях Apache (2.2 и 2.4) и функциональных возможностей отличных друг от друга версий, ну и в корявости дефолтных .htaccess Wordpress =)

Само изменение правила, будь то закомментирование или отсутствие цикла ни на что не влияют.

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос был немного в другом. То, что нужно закомментировать эту строку я уже понял, в своем вопросе я это описал. Вопрос в том, на что влияет эта строка и не сломается ли что-то на сайте если я её закомментирую? Внешне вроде все работает, но я не уверен, что "внутри" все работает корректно.

Comment: изменил ответ, ознакомьтесь

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! :)